# How to set the Bluetooth device automatically connect and disconnect in flutter?

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

```
 import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:blue_thermal_printer_example/testprint.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:blue_thermal_printer/blue_thermal_printer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
 BlueThermalPrinter bluetooth = BlueThermalPrinter.instance;

 List<BluetoothDevice> _devices = [];
 BluetoothDevice _device;
 bool _connected = false;
 String pathImage;
 TestPrint testPrint;

 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   initPlatformState();
   initSavetoPath();
   testPrint = TestPrint();
 }

 initSavetoPath() async {
   //read and write
   //image max 300px X 300px
   final filename = 'yourlogo.png';
   var bytes = await rootBundle.load("assets/images/yourlogo.png");
   String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
   writeToFile(bytes, '$dir/$filename');
   setState(() {
     pathImage = '$dir/$filename';
   });
 }

 Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
   bool isConnected = await bluetooth.isConnected;
   List<BluetoothDevice> devices = [];
   try {
     devices = await bluetooth.getBondedDevices();
   } on PlatformException {
     // TODO - Error
   }

   bluetooth.onStateChanged().listen((state) {
     switch (state) {
       case BlueThermalPrinter.CONNECTED:
         setState(() {
           _connected = true;
         });
         break;
       case BlueThermalPrinter.DISCONNECTED:
         setState(() {
           _connected = false;
         });
         break;
       default:
         print(state);
         break;
     }
   });

   if (!mounted) return;
   setState(() {
     _devices = devices;
   });

   if (isConnected) {
     setState(() {
       _connected = true;
     });
   }
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
     home: Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
         title: Text('Blue Thermal Printer'),
       ),
       body: Container(
         child: Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
           child: ListView(
             children: <Widget>[
               Row(
                 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                 children: <Widget>[
                   SizedBox(
                     width: 10,
                   ),
                   Text(
                     'Device:',
                     style: TextStyle(
                       fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                     ),
                   ),
                   SizedBox(
                     width: 30,
                   ),
                   Expanded(
                     child: DropdownButton(
                       items: _getDeviceItems(),
                       onChanged: (value) => setState(() => _device = value),
                       value: _device,
                     ),
                   ),
                 ],
               ),
               SizedBox(
                 height: 10,
               ),
               Row(
                 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                 children: <Widget>[
                   ElevatedButton(
                     style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.brown),
                     onPressed: () {
                       initPlatformState();
                     },
                     child: Text(
                       'Refresh',
                       style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                     ),
                   ),
                   SizedBox(
                     width: 20,
                   ),
                   ElevatedButton(
                     style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                         primary: _connected ? Colors.red : Colors.green),
                     onPressed: _connected ? _disconnect : _connect,
                     child: Text(
                       _connected ? 'Disconnect' : 'Connect',
                       style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                     ),
                   ),
                 ],
               ),
               Padding(
                 padding:
                     const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 50),
                 child: ElevatedButton(
                   style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.brown),
                   onPressed: () {
                     testPrint.sample(pathImage);
                   },
                   child: Text('PRINT TEST',
                       style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                 ),
               ),
             ],
           ),
         ),
       ),
     ),
   );
 }

 List<DropdownMenuItem<BluetoothDevice>> _getDeviceItems() {
   List<DropdownMenuItem<BluetoothDevice>> items = [];
   if (_devices.isEmpty) {
     items.add(DropdownMenuItem(
       child: Text('NONE'),
     ));
   } else {
     _devices.forEach((device) {
       items.add(DropdownMenuItem(
         child: Text(device.name),
         value: device,
       ));
     });
   }
   return items;
 }

 void _connect() {
   if (_device == null) {
     show('No device selected.');
   } else {
     bluetooth.isConnected.then((isConnected) {
       if (!isConnected) {
         bluetooth.connect(_device).catchError((error) {
           setState(() => _connected = false);
         });
         setState(() => _connected = true);
       }
     });
   }
 }

 void _disconnect() {
   bluetooth.disconnect();
   setState(() => _connected = false);
   
 }

//write to app path
 Future<void> writeToFile(ByteData data, String path) {
   final buffer = data.buffer;
   return new File(path).writeAsBytes(
       buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes));
 }

 Future show(
   String message, {
   Duration duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
 }) async {
   await new Future.delayed(new Duration(milliseconds: 100));
   ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
     new SnackBar(
       content: new Text(
         message,
         style: new TextStyle(
           color: Colors.white,
         ),
       ),
       duration: duration,
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

for this code is need to pressed the button then can connect the bluetooth device and disconnect the bluetooth device.

So my problem is how to write the code to let it automatically connect the bluetooth device after select the device mean that I no need to pressed any button just select the device then it can auto connect the device that I have select.

For disconnect the bluetooth device, I want to make it automatically disconnect after I print out which is after I print out the thing then the bluetooth device will auto disconnect.

I am new in flutter. Please help to find the solution. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I might try to help for your answer, so I'm doing this code :
You have to use 'await' for delaying the printer to connect and disconnnect.

```
void _connect(BluetoothDevice selectedDevice) {
 if (selectedDevice == null) {
   _devicesMsg = 'No device selected.';
 } else {
   printer.isConnected.then((isConnected) {
     if (!isConnected) {
        printer.connect(selectedDevice).catchError((error) {
          _devicesMsg = 'Device Error.';
        });
      }
    });
  }
}


Future<void> _startPrint() async {
//SIZE
// 0- normal size text
// 1- only bold text
// 2- bold with medium text
// 3- bold with large text
//ALIGN
// 0- ESC_ALIGN_LEFT
// 1- ESC_ALIGN_CENTER
// 2- ESC_ALIGN_RIGHT
await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 2000));
printer.isConnected.then((isConnected) {
   if (isConnected) {
     printer.printNewLine();
     printer.printCustom("HEADER", 3, 1);
     printer.paperCut();
    }
  });
}
```

and try to disconnect after you have successfully to print out the data.

```
Future<void> _disconnect() async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 3000));
  printer.disconnect();
}
```

finally you can use Modal Bottom Sheet to completely your print button :

```
void _settingModalBottomSheet(context) {
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext bc) {
      return Container(
        height: 100,
        child: _devices.isEmpty
            ? Center(child: Text(_devicesMsg ?? ''))
            : ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _devices.length,
                itemBuilder: (c, i) {
                  return ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.print),
                    title: Text(
                      _devices[i].name,
                      style: whiteNumberFont.copyWith(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 14,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(_devices[i].address),
                    onTap: () {
                      _connect(_devices[i]);
                      _startPrint();
                      _disconnect();
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
          );
       });
   }
```

print button like this:

```
ElevatedButton(
 style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          elevation: 0,
          primary: mainColor,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
          ),
          child: Text(
              "PRINT",
              style: whiteTextFont.copyWith(
              fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            _settingModalBottomSheet(context);
          },
      ),
```